# SQL Join two "month" tables the fastest way?

Tags: sql-server

I have a View called LOGS2016 that is created from 12 individual "Month" tables of naming convention: LOG201601, LOG201602, and so on..

To do normal date range lookups, I'll typically select all records from LOGS2016 and do a DATEADD function on each record. Obviously not the fastest method.

My filter is only ever attempting to find "previous 30 days worth of activity from today", so what I'd like to do is use only 2 tables to cover this query, as opposed to the entire year VIEW which is 12 tables worth of records.

Is there a way to do a join or union on the current month's table and the previous month's table instead of using the annual VIEW? (I can get current year and month using PHP if necessary)

What I've tried (and is still very slow):

```
-- This takes 11 Seconds
SELECT * FROM LOG201612 WITH (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM LOG201701 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: The above query is as simple as it gets. What do you have in your tables? how many records? What indexes?

Comment: Add DDL and the query you are using to your question. With a clustered index on date and a sargable `WHERE` clause expression in the , I would expect the annual view to perform just as well.